# Detect physical heartbeat using the front facing camera

Tags: android, ios, camera, health-monitoring

I want to detect the user's physical heartbeat using the front-facing camera of the phone.

Some apps detect heartbeat in the finger using micro changes of the red color intensity of the finger, while turning on the led flash.

I'm interested in learning the user's heartbeat based on their facial red color intensity.

The solution can take into account that the lighting is ideal and only the red color intensity of the user's face is changing.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?
Is there a ready made algorithm for that?
Did anyone write an implementation for that?

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt such a thing would be physically possible. Blood flow in the face is not the same as in the finger and you would need a very powerful light and camera to detect it.

Comment: I have never heard of any apps that do this and would be interested in a link. I think such apps might be like the "x-ray" apps in the PlayStore - pure bullshit.

Comment: I doubt this is possible with a sh***y phone camera, and cross plattform (i assume because of the ios tag) makes it even harder.

Comment: To the contrary, I have seen a TED talk where they did exactly what you are talking about. I think they were using OpenCV on a laptop. You'd need to isolate the face and then a sensitive filter that would isolate and amplify the red level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed it's possible. Take a look at this TED talk that demonstrates exactly that. In the video the presenter provides a link that includes the source code, as well as pre-built tools that do that sort of processing on existing video:

http://www.ted.com/talks/michael_rubinstein_see_invisible_motion_hear_silent_sounds_cool_creepy_we_can_t_decide?language=en

Comment: If you are going to reference the TED talk, then at least reference the project page: http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/#code along with the fact that the source code itself is in Matlab and only for "non-commercial research purposes only."

Comment: I actually didn't follow the links from the talk until after I posted my answer. At that point I found that they were dead. Thanks for providing the correct links to the Matlab code.